# Shape of a water balloon laying on the ground

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis

I would like to know if you are aware of any litterature or any way to solve the following problem: what is the equation that describes the shape of a ballon filled with an arbitrary quantity of water laying on the ground.

For example on the following picture you can see a reservoir of water for firemen, what I'm looking for is the equation describing the section.

[image: Water reservoir for firemen]

Here I made a diagram, on the left I assume the natural shape of the balloon/reservoir is a sphere, I then add some water, it make the balloon more flatish.

[image: Diagram of the reservoir]

I expect the solution to depend of $g$, the elasticity of the material $\nu$, the volume of water $V$, the radius of the initial sphere $R_i$.
Thanks,

Comment: I have seen soft body simulations that treat the balloon as shell of point masses connected by springs. These shells are filled with an ideal gas and pressurized using the ideal gas law: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228574502_How_to_implement_a_pressure_soft_body_model.

Comment: I will check this out thank you!